# Delete ALL files and directories in trash

Tags: scripts, ubuntu-mate

I am trying to delete every file and directory in the Trash directory.

I know I can just empty the trash, but this part of a cronjob.

I have this and it works on Most files, but not all.

```
rm /home/andy/.local/share/Trash/expunged/*
rm -r /home/andy/.local/share/Trash/files/*
rm /home/andy/.local/share/Trash/files/.*
rm /home/andy/.local/share/Trash/info/*
```

It does not remove the directory.

.PeaZip

Is there a command that will remove EVERYTHING?

Comment: Ubuntu Mate 18.04 I want files deleted much sooner.

Comment: @user68186 It did not work.

Comment: @user68186 My question is not a duplicate. Patience is a virtue. I posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
rm /home/andy/.local/share/Trash/expunged/*
rm -r -f /home/andy/.local/share/Trash/files/*
rm /home/andy/.local/share/Trash/files/*.*
```

## This deletes .directories

rm -r /home/andy/.local/share/Trash/files/.*